# Android studio auto generated code in DataBinderMapperImpl error must either be declared abstract

Tags: java, android, xml, data-binding

My Android studio project shows strange error in auto generated code, but unable to find what the reason for that.

The project compiles and runs, but the data binding not work. Any of the property of view model, are not retrieved or set by the user interface. Rest of the things are working properly. But the data binding worked fine a day ago without any issue.

The error I'm getting is: Class 'DataBinderMapperImpl' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent, View, int)' in 'DataBinderMapper'

Error shows here in the auto generated code;

```
public class DataBinderMapperImpl extends DataBinderMapper {
```

I think its useless to fix error in this auto generated class, because it will be overwritten automatically. But I'm unable to figure out what part of my application need to be checked to identify and fix the issue.

xml data bind variable

```
    <data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="doc"
        type="com.ourshops.shops.ourshops.view_models.VM_Doc_Cus_Order"
        />
    </data>
```

controller

```
<EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtCusPhoneMobile"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:hint=""
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#8b4513"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
                            android:inputType="phone"
                            android:text="@={doc.CusPhoneMobile}"
                            />
```

property

```
  @Bindable
public String getCusPhoneMobile() {
    return _doc.Tel_Mobile;
}
@Bindable
public void setCusPhoneMobile(String cusPhoneMobile) {
    if(_doc.Tel_Mobile != cusPhoneMobile) {
        _doc.Tel_Mobile = cusPhoneMobile;
        _doc.Tel_LandPhone = _doc.Tel_Mobile;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.cusPhoneMobile);
    }
}
```

but here

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" shows it's never used. But the Android documentation shows this need to be exist for data binding. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding#java

Can anyone please point me in right direction to identify the issue? I'm struggling with this issue for two days now, but not found enough resource to solve the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.